# cookie jar not required for HTTPCookieProcessor?

Tags: python, urllib2

In every example I've seen about storing PHP session values and viewing protected web pages in python with urllib2, a cookie jar ( `cookielib.CookieJar()` ) is always passed like so:

```
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

Someone was playing with this code and removed the cookiejar altogether, but is still able to view session protected web pages with this script:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())

formValues = {
    "username":"user",
    "password":"pass"
}
data = urllib.urlencode(formValues)
response = opener.open("http://jshawl.com/python-playground/login.php", data)
print response.read()
secure = opener.open("http://jshawl.com/python-playground/protected2.php")
print secure.read() # prints content that is only viewable if $_SESSION variable is correct.
```

How are the $_SESSION variables being stored without a cookie jar?

Comment: Are you sure that the session isn't stored at server side instead? I can't explain the phenomenon elseway :)

Comment: Just like this: if ($_POST['username'] == "user" && $_POST['password'] == "pass") {
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1; } Then the pages protected and protected2.php only say 'you are logged in' if $_SESSION['loggedin']==1

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of HTTPCookieProcessor has a default value of None for the cookie jar argument. In this case, HTTPCookieProcessor instantiates a new, empty cookie jar.

See also http://books.google.de/books?id=kQom0WiUbZQC&pg=PA438&lpg=PA438&dq=HTTPCookieProcessor&source=bl&ots=mrCFWZE_8q&sig=CEON7tOOalWEpePQsbVVa0XNzV0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v9BNU4WtHpKkyAPZ3YGgDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=HTTPCookieProcessor&f=falsehttp://books.google.de/books?id=kQom0WiUbZQC&pg=PA438&lpg=PA438&dq=HTTPCookieProcessor&source=bl&ots=mrCFWZE_8q&sig=CEON7tOOalWEpePQsbVVa0XNzV0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v9BNU4WtHpKkyAPZ3YGgDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=HTTPCookieProcessor&f=false